# How to change the value of x in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

Using a for loop, while iterating over a list, is it possible to change the value of x?
For example,

```
>>> myList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> for x in myList:
...     print x
```

If I change the value of x, then it will have an effect in the current iteration, but not on the next one. Using the code from above, if the following were added,

```
...     x += 1
...     print x
```

Then it would print out:

```
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
9
10
```

Why is it that the value of x is able to be changed, but loses its changes once it is changed by the loop itself. Also, it is possible to get around this?
Thanks

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? What do you want to accomplish? This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242).

Comment: As a general rule you should not modify the thing you are looping over inside the loop; because this makes your loop condition variable (subject to change), and thus a source of bugs. Are you trying to solve a problem with this? Perhaps there is a better way.  Try describing the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Suppose your list is `[0, 5, 2, 1, 3]`, and you try to do `x += 1` in a way that persists across iterations. What should happen?

Answer (score 2):

`x` is a different variable for each loop iteration. It's also immutable, so none of the changes you make to it are visible from the original list. If you want to change the value of the element in the list, you'd have to do this:

```
>>> myList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> for i,_ in enumerate(myList):
...     myList[i] += 1
...     print myList[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[x+1 for x in some_list]
```

this is what list comprehensions are for ...

when you do this

```
for x in some_list:
    x += 1 #this only changes the local x
    #it does not change the value in the list
```

if you want to replace the values in the list you can do

```
some_list[:] = [x+1 for x in some_list]
```

^ this will modify the existing memory of the list

```
some_list = [x+1 for x in some_list]
```

will overwrite the variable `some_list` with a new list, and garbage collect the old one (pretty immediately typically)

Comment: Strictly speaking, this does not modify the original list but creates a new one.

Comment: yeah i know ... but this is probably hat he should do ... well Im not entirely sure what he is trying to do ... edited to offer a solution to use the same memory locations

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I properly understand your question, but I'll take a crack at it.  You're not changing the value of `myList`.  You're only changing the value of a `x`.  The for loop's "variable" (in this case `x`) is only a means of accessing each ***item*** in an iterable (in this case `myList`).  In other words, the x is a "variable" that represents each new item as you "step through" myList.  Thus, `x` "pops in and out of existence" if you will, while myList remains unchanged at its original memory location.

If you want to change the original list, then you need to do as Joran Beasley explains.

reference your entire list (note that he "grabs" the whole list by indexing the list in its entirety with `[:]`).

```
myList[:] = [x+1 for x in myList] #now you've changed the value of myList in the memory location where it was originally created and still "lives"
```

if you want to create a different list altogether, then you can create a new variable and set it equal to a list comprehension (or using a `for loop`, set it equal to an empty list to which you append the contents of your new list).

list comp:

```
myNewList = [x**2 for x in myList]
```

or for loop:

```
myNewList = []
for x in myList:
    myNewList.append(x**2)
```